# How to read a line from continuously written log file

Tags: shell, unix, while-loop

I am new bee for shell scripting so if you find this post is redundant please redirect me to existing post.

I have jar command which run in background and keep on updating log file.
I am automating this process and writing shell script. I am using below code. Please help me to figure out what am I missing.

```
java -jar fileName.jar &
pid=$!
echo $!
cd /usr/ebp/logs/
logs=$(ls -t | head -n 1)   #trying to read latest log file from directory
tail -f ${logs} | while read LOGLINE
do
   if [ "${LOGLINE}" == *"Batch process completed successfully"* ]
   then
                echo ${LOGLINE}
                echo "csv files created successfully"
                break
   fi
done
kill -9 ${pid}
```

Once batch process is completed I want to kill jar process id. But I am not able to read log file and it is stuck in while loop.

Comment: Why is the jar still running? Can't you exit out of loop there when done? Good luck.

Comment: You aren't setting `pid` properly; spaces are not allowed on either side of the `=`. Use `pid=$!`.

Comment: @Shelter: you have mentioned, can't you exit out of loop there when done? How will I know jar execution is completed? This jar is written such a way that it will keep on running unless process id is killed. To know jar is completed execution I am reading log file.

Comment: `tail -f` will not exit therefore ` | while` will keep running. The `if` condition will evaluate to false because `[ ... ]` doesn't use regex. Replace it with `if [[ .... ]]`. When `| while` terminates, `tail` will fail with broken pipe.

Comment: Hi @ShikhaA : Yes, I understand you want to kill a running jar. What I don't understand is, if your java code emits a message "Batch process completed successfully", why isn't there an `exit` in the code right after that? You write "Once batch process is completed I want to kill jar ". I don't see why the jar can't "kill" itself. A batch process is different that a server process. Add a switch to your java code that indicates "batch_mode" or "server_mode", when it batch_mode, let the java code close down when the processing is complete. That's the way I see it, anyway;-)  Good luck!